# OpenJPA usage of Log4j brakes OpenJPA enhancement build

Tags: java, log4j, openjpa

I had some issues with OpenJPA logging. As someone suggested, I've tried to set OpenJPA to use log4j, and to include the following line in my persistence.xml:

```
<property name="openjpa.Log" value="log4j"/>
```

But it's immediately broke the openJPA enhance process:

```
openJPA_enhance.xml:26: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Priority
```

**Update**
(Aninda Thank you for your help).

After I've included openJpa.jar, the OpenJPA Enhancer now failing to load log4j.properties. 
I included Log4j properties in the classpath and a jvm argument: "-Dlog4j.configuration"

I cannot get pass an Exception from OpenJPA:

```
Buildfile: ../Workspaces_JEE/ETM_Workspace/ETM/openJPA_enhance.xml

openjpa.libs.check:

build.dir.check:

enhance:
        [echo] /home/jamad/Workspaces/Workspaces_JEE/ETM/build/classes:/home/jamad/Workspaces/Workspaces_JEE/ETM/src/META-INF/log4j.properties
    [openjpac] log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (openjpa.Runtime).
    [openjpac] log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    [openjpac] log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Unable to obtain resource from /home/jamad/Workspaces/Workspaces_JEE/ETM/src/META-INF/log4j.properties: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    [openjpac] Unable to obtain resource from /home/jamad/Workspaces/Workspaces_JEE/ETM_Workspace/ETM/src/META-INF/log4j.properties: 
    [openjpac] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    [openjpac]  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you have the log4j jar added to your classpath? Also, what is the application server you are deploying it to?

Comment: And what server you are deploying to? If you are using websphere, there is a related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254857/openjpa-webspere-7-log4j-configuration

Comment: It's a standalone application (no server). I am using Eclipse. The OpenJPA/Log4j is on the build class path. And everything is working just fine (log4j and OpenJPA inside and outside Eclipse (as executable jar) ). The problem occur only when I  enable: <property name="openjpa.Log" value="log4j" />

Comment: Aninda, thank you. You were right, it's the class path for the Enhancer. The issue is resolved.